# Altium - Use Net Tie on a Plane Layer

Tags: altium

Is it possible to use a net tie on a *plane* layer? I know how to use a net tie to connect two different polygon pours together. But how would one go about this on a plane layer -- which is a negative layer?

Comment: I don’t think its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best alternative I managed to come up with so far is to convert the *plane* layers into *signal* layers in the **Stackup Manager** then use ordinary polygon pours on the new signal layers instead of split planes. The only inconvenience this will cause is that one has to remember not to leave any areas un-poured by accident.